# Parent child GROUP_CONCAT on same table joining on wrong reference

Tags: mysql, sql

One table is storing a parent/ child relationship. I'm trying to get a return where the entries `parent_id` returns the parents name + child's name as a new column. The structure is as follows:

#### Table structure

| label_template_category_id | name | parent_id | sort_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 'Christmas' | 0 | 4 |
| 7 | 'Father's Day' | 34 | 6 |
| 9 | 'Mother's Day' | 34 | 8 |
| 10 | 'New Baby' | 34 | 9 |
| 11 | 'New Home' | 34 | 10 |
| 13 | 'Thank You' | 0 | 12 |
| 14 | 'Wedding' | 0 | 13 |
| 15 | 'Business' | 0 | 0 |
| 16 | 'Valentine's Day' | 34 | 0 |
| 26 | 'New Year' | 0 | 0 |
| 28 | 'Retirement' | 0 | 0 |
| 29 | 'Sports Events/ Teams' | 0 | 0 |
| 34 | 'Celebration Days' | 0 | 0 |

#### Expected Results

| label_template_category_id | name | parent_id | sort_order | group_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 'Christmas' | 0 | 4 | 'Christmas' |
| 7 | 'Father's Day' | 34 | 6 | 'Celebration Days > Father's Day' |
| 9 | 'Mother's Day' | 34 | 8 | 'Celebration Days > Mother's Day' |
| 10 | 'New Baby' | 34 | 9 | 'Celebration Days > New Baby' |
| 11 | 'New Home' | 34 | 10 | 'Celebration Days > New Home' |
| 13 | 'Thank You' | 0 | 12 | 'Thank You' |
| 14 | 'Wedding' | 0 | 13 | 'Wedding' |
| 15 | 'Business' | 0 | 0 | 'Business' |
| 16 | 'Valentine's Day' | 34 | 0 | 'Celebration Days > Valentine's Day' |
| 26 | 'New Year' | 0 | 0 | 'New Year' |
| 28 | 'Retirement' | 0 | 0 | 'Retirement' |
| 29 | 'Sports Events/ Teams' | 0 | 0 | 'Sports Events/ Teams' |
| 34 | 'Celebration Days' | 0 | 0 | 'Celebration Days' |

Using the following query I'm getting all the children returning on the parent instead of on the child like the expected results above.

```
SELECT     
    parent.label_template_category_id,
    parent.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(child.name SEPARATOR ' &gt; ') group_name 
    FROM label_template_category parent
    LEFT JOIN label_template_category child 
      ON (child.parent_id = parent.label_template_category_id)
    GROUP BY parent.label_template_category_id 
      ORDER BY group_name
```

Actual returned results

| label_template_category_id | name | parent_id | sort_order | group_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 'Wedding' | 0 | 13 |  |
| 15 | 'Business' | 0 | 0 |  |
| 16 | 'Valentine's Day' | 34 | 0 |  |
| 34 | 'Celebration Days' | 0 | 0 | 'Father's Day > Mother's Day > New Baby > New Home > Valentine's Day' |

I've created an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30a0ea/1) for testing.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a `GROUP_CONCAT()` for this. And the order of `LEFT JOIN` seems the other way around. Try this query:

```
SELECT     
    child.label_template_category_id,
    child.name,
    child.parent_id,
    child.sort_order,
    CASE WHEN parent.name IS NULL THEN child.name ELSE 
         CONCAT_WS(' > ',parent.name, child.name) END AS group_name 
         /*or maybe CONCAT_WS(' &gt; ',parent.name, child.name) END AS group_name */
    
FROM label_template_category child
LEFT JOIN label_template_category parent 
      ON (child.parent_id = parent.label_template_category_id);
```

You need a [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement with [CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function. As you can see, I switched the `LEFT JOIN` where the `child` is set as reference instead. Then I'm doing a `CASE` when the result from parent is `NULL` it will return the data in column `child.name`. Otherwise, if there's a match, it will concatenate `parent.name` with `child.name`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2964b2d041c7c2818d8546d46999116f)